# Extra argument 'error' in callのエラー対策について

Tags: swift

サイトや他の質問で do try catch を入れることで対策できるということは解ったのですが、それらをどこに入れるのかが解らないため質問させていただきました。

```
import Foundation
var urlString = "http://www.apple.com"
var url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
var htmlString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

どうかご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純にエラー処理を入れるだけであれば、こんな感じになります。

```
import Foundation

let urlString = "http://www.apple.com"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

do {
    let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
    let htmlString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    // htmlStringを使った処理
    // print(htmlString)

} catch let error {

    // エラー処理
    print(error)
}
```

実際に使うのであれば、NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest()はiOS9でdeprecatedになっているので、NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest()を使う形に書きなおしたほうが良いかと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！初めて１ヶ月の人間なので、どうなってるのなんのこっちゃ。。。て感じですが、しっかり勉強していきたいと思います。ご親切にありがとうございました。